# Fancybox default close button - on close button function

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

How can I write a function when user clicks on default close button in fancybox 2?
Whenever I hover on close button, it shows me `javascript:;` in Chrome.

Here is the image[image: Close Button]

Comment: so? does my answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `tpl` API option to your custom script and remove the `href` attribute from the close button template like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    tpl: {
        closeBtn: '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close"></a>'
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SAcCD/)**